Strange behavior of nativewind in expo application, half working, half not
This is very weird, here is an example of what exactly is happening

import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function EditScreenInfo({ path }: { path: string }) {
  return (
    <>
      <View className='mt-12 items-center'>
        <Text>Open up the code for this screen:</Text>
      </View>
      <View className='mt-12'>
        <Text className='text-center'>
          Change any of the text, save the file, and your app will automatically
          update.
        </Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

The problem is that if you change 12 in mt-12 to any other number, mt will stop working
and text-center not working as well

import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

export default function EditScreenInfo({ path }: { path: string }) {
  return (
    <>
      <View className='mt-12 items-center'>
        <Text>Open up the code for this screen:</Text>
      </View>
      <View className='mt-10'>
        <Text className='text-center'>
          Change any of the text, save the file, and your app will automatically
          update.
        </Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

see? I changed
<View className='mt-12'>
  <Text className='text-center'>
     Change any of the text, save the file, and your app will automatically
     update.
  </Text>
</View>

to
<View className='mt-10'>
  <Text className='text-center'>
     Change any of the text, save the file, and your app will automatically
     update.
  </Text>
</View>

className='mt-12' to className='mt-10'
and it stopped working, no matter what number I enter there, it only works with mt-12, why is that?
"nativewind": "^4.1.23",
"tailwindcss": "^3.4.16"

implemented everything according to the documentation
I tried restarting via npx expo start --clear without cache, but mt-10 still didn't apply after that

It turned out that in their documentation in tailwind.config.js, there was no path for the styles to be applied to the components folder, that was the problem.
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  // NOTE: Update this to include the paths to all of your component files.
  darkMode: "class",
  content: ["./app/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  presets: [require("nativewind/preset")],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};


added "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"

I don´t know why mt-12 worked though.
